# How do we get title for an abandoned vehicle?

Tags: probate, motor-vehicle

I have a motorcycle sitting in my garage where the owner, my friend,  committed suicide.  The deceased owner's brother lives in another state and claims that he has the title that the deceased transferred to his name before the suicide.  I have tried to negotiate with the brother of the deceased for selling the motorcycle and splitting the proceeds.

So far the brother has not responded and claims he is still looking for the transferred title.  The brother is the only living relative to the deceased but is not an heir to deceased's estate since his lawyer advised him to walk away from inheriting the estate for liability reasons.

Since the deceased's brother did not inherit the estate and has not produced said motorcycle's title, how do I go about getting a clean title for the abandoned motorcycle?  I live in New Jersey, USA.

Comment: My condolences on the loss of your friend.  I don't think you can get the title - that can usually only be done by the rightful owner.  If the title really was transferred to the brother, then he's the owner. If not, then it belongs to the estate, and the executor (possibly a court-appointed official) should be able to get the title.

Comment: At some point you can acquire title to a vehicle by adverse possession against the true owner. In Colorado the adverse possession period for personal property is three years. I don't know what it is in New Jersey.